# Trying to display MongoDB documents content on my front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, react-fullstack

I am currently struggling displaying the contents of my database in my front end components. I am using the MERN stack to create a grocery list app and so far, I have a form with an onsubmit event in my front end that is sending data to MongoDB and saving it. I see what I am submitting in my database without a problem.

To display the data I have created a backend route where I find the list in my database
[backend route image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgIOZ.png)

then I make an api to that backend route via a gentlest action I create
[getlist api action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSmXU.png)

I try calling his action in my front end component but all I see is an empty array in my console not a populated list of any sort.  In the past I make the api call then set the state of whatever I need to set and map through that to display it . Let me know if you guys have any ideas

[frontend component to show the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxNLG.png)

Comment: Please add the code snippets to the post instead of images

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way you communicate with your backend api is by performing a request via axios or fetch.

If you use axios  then create a function and  perform a post request to your backend route inside it. Then call that function inside useEffect.

If you are using redux then simply call the action inside useEffect.

Edit:
Let's assume that your server is listening to port 8000 for this example
`

```
 const [groceryList, setGroceryList] = useState([]);

 async function fetchData() {
 const result = await axios.get(`/http://localhost:8000/getList`);
 setGroceryList(result);
  }

 useEffect(() => {
 fetchData()
 },[])
```

`

Comment: I think a little code snippet here would really help.

Answer (score 0):

All You Need To Do:

```
import {useEffect,useState } from "react";
 
//use it inside your function component in JS file and make sure your //server 3001 is runing by using express
function abcd(){

const [object, setObj] = useState([
    {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      url: "",
    },
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/pages")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((jsonRes) => setObj(jsonRes));
  }, []);


//Render

return(
 <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          width: "20%",
          margin: "auto auto",
        }}
      >
        {object
          .sort((a, b) => {
            var titleA = a.title;
            var titleB = b.title;
            if (titleA < titleB) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (titleA > titleB) {
              return 1;
            }
            return 0;
          })
          .map((Ob) => {
            return (
              <img
                key={Ob.title}
                src={Ob.url}
                alt={Ob.description}
                name={Ob.title}
                onClick={handleClick}
              ></img>
            );
          })}
      </div>)
}

//Use the below code in your BackEnd in order to fetch all the data from the //MongoBackEnd(Express)
//Use your MongoDB server address and mongoSchema and store it in a //Variable("Handle")

const Handle = require("./views/mongoschema");

  app.get("/pages", (req, res) => {
      Handle.find({})
        .then((items) => res.json(items))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });
```

By doing the above things you can fetch all the MongoDB data in the frontEnd and add designs or Templates to it.